# I'm trying MongoDB with Mongoose, but it throwing an error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to MERN. I faced an issue while using MongoDB with Mongoose. Genuinely, I have no idea about it. An error like this:

const err = new MongooseError(message);

MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB', {useNewUrlParser: true});

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model('Fruit', fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
    name: "Banana",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Much loved."
});

fruit.save();
```

Full form of error in terminal:

```
C:\Bekhruz's  Coding Journey\Bekhruz's Progress\MongooseApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `fruits.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Bekhruz's  Coding Journey\Bekhruz's Progress\MongooseApp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:151:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)

Node.js v17.7.2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like Mongoose couldn't connect to your MongoDB properly.

Comment: @robertklep What is the reason? An internet connection speed?

Comment: You're connecting to a local MongoDB, so internet connection speed isn't important.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `await` at `mongoose.connect()` function. And handle errors with `catch` function as shown in [this link.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling)

Comment: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Causing another error(

Comment: if you use top level bodies then you should cover whole code block by ```.then()``` in order to make this async

Comment: Could you share the code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Make a top level async function to wait for the MongoDB to connect

Try/Catch your `save()` function.

```
(async () => {
  // put your new code here

  await mongoose.connect(/* URL */, { useNewUrlParser: true });

  //...
  
  try {
    fruit.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Couldn\'t save fruit!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

kindly check if you are connected with your DB.

```
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_URL,
  options
)
.then(()=>console.log('connected'))
.catch(e=>console.log(e));
```

This shall throw a proper error that can be used for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might also be following **Angela Yu's** web development course, and if you are, I have a solution for your issue. I found that using the **current version of Node.js**, rather than the latest version, was the key to resolving the problem. I tried everything, and in the end, updating Node.js to the current version was what really made a difference. I hope this helps!

Best regards,
Mohit